# HMAC-SHA256 in Python is producing different output to Nodejs

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, hmac, hashlib

I have a python script which uses the HMAC-hashlib.sha256 algorithm to generate a signature to authenticate over API.

```
# ZenEmu
import base64
import hashlib
import hmac
import json
from datetime import datetime
import requests

data = json.dumps(
    {
        "version": "1",
        "id": "284512",
        "created": "2023-01-17T02:26:29Z",
        "updated": "2023-01-17T02:26:29Z",
        "url": "https://hitchhikerio.zendesk.com/agent/tickets/284512",
        "type": "Question",
        "status": "Closed",
        "priority": "Low",
        "title": "[TEST4] Please Ignore!",
        "description": "first comment",
        "tags": "test",
        "requester_email": "cedric.damian@gmail.com",
        "assignee_email": "admin.castle@gmail.com",
        "latest_comment": {
                "id": "6586310212693",
                "is_public": "true",
                "author_email": "admin.castle@gmail.com",
                "body": "second reply!",
        },

    }

).encode('utf-8')


sig = base64.b64encode(
    hmac.new(
        "secret".encode("utf-8"),
        "2022-10-10T04:42:00Z".encode("utf-8") + data,
        hashlib.sha256,
    ).digest()
)


print(sig)
```

This python file pirnts this result as the signature (sig) = `b'DJXG/w1ARbM2ZOQ3pamMEkNY7qSJXpjbQMsARyWCr0Y='`

I have tried converting this to Javascript with the help of my colleagues and referring to similar questions and resources online to no avail

This is my Javascript file

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const utf8 = require('utf8')

const data = utf8.encode(JSON.stringify({
        version: "1",
        id: "284512",
        created: "2023-01-17T02:26:29Z",
        updated: "2023-01-17T02:26:29Z",
        url: "https://hitchhikerio.zendesk.com/agent/tickets/284512",
        type: "Question",
        status: "Closed",
        priority: "Low",
        title: "[TEST4] Please Ignore!",
        description: "first comment",
        tags: "test",
        requester_email: "cedric.muuo@tradecore.com",
        assignee_email: "admin.castle@tradecore.com",
        latest_comment: {
            id: "6586310212693",
            is_public: "true",
            author_email: "admin.castle@tradecore.com",
            body: "second reply!",
        },
    }));

    console.log(data);

    const sig = crypto
        .createHmac('sha256', utf8.encode('secret'))
        .update(utf8.encode("2022-10-10T04:42:00Z") + data)
        .digest('base64')

    console.log(sig);
```

which prints the output `Yqi7WvMPxdSlo5Vb9YlcbX2zu5aQpungXhuCYx3bc+4=`

How do I get the Javascript code to generate the same output as the python script? (`b'DJXG/w1ARbM2ZOQ3pamMEkNY7qSJXpjbQMsARyWCr0Y='`)

EDIT: THE PYTHON FILE SHOULD STAY UNCHANGED, IT PRODUCES THE CORRECT OUTPUT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON strings aren't identical. Python outputs the following:

```
'{"version": "1", "id": "284512", "created": "2023-01-17T02:26:29Z", "updated": "2023-01-17T02:26:29Z", "url": "https://hitchhikerio.zendesk.com/agent/tickets/284512", "type": "Question", "status": "Closed", "priority": "Low", "title": "[TEST4] Please Ignore!", "description": "first comment", "tags": "test", "requester_email": "cedric.damian@gmail.com", "assignee_email": "admin.castle@gmail.com", "latest_comment": {"id": "6586310212693", "is_public": "true", "author_email": "admin.castle@gmail.com", "body": "second reply!"}}'
```

Node outputs the following:

```
'{"version":"1","id":"284512","created":"2023-01-17T02:26:29Z","updated":"2023-01-17T02:26:29Z","url":"https://hitchhikerio.zendesk.com/agent/tickets/284512","type":"Question","status":"Closed","priority":"Low","title":"[TEST4] Please Ignore!","description":"first comment","tags":"test","requester_email":"cedric.muuo@tradecore.com","assignee_email":"admin.castle@tradecore.com","latest_comment":{"id":"6586310212693","is_public":"true","author_email":"admin.castle@tradecore.com","body":"second reply!"}}'
```

Notice how the Node version has no whitespace.

EDIT:

To fix it, you can use the Python function as follows:

```py
json.dumps(your_data_object_here, separators=(",",":"))
```

Edit again:

To insert spaces into the Node version you can try the following:

```js
JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/("[^"]+"[:,])/g, "$1 ");
```

That should insert spaces after all the `:` and `,`, like in Python. Note that it does not handle escaped quote marks inside the strings. You'll need to update the Regex to deal with that.

Final edit:

Here's an alternate JS approach:

```js
const data = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 1).match(/(\S.*)/gm).join("");
```

This constructs a "pretty-printed" JSON string with newlines and everything, then grabs each line starting at the first non-whitespace and joins them all up. That strips newlines and indentation, but preserves all whitespace between separators and inside strings. Should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks you, however, I don't want to change the python script. It should remain unchanged since it produces the correct signature. I want to modify the javascript file to produce the same signature as the python script

Comment: @damian-sketch Who says Python is the one that produces the correct signature? Who defines what's correct?

Comment: That is the signature we are using to authenticate when sending requests on our company API. My aim here is to have a javascript file which generates the exact same signature as the signature by the python file which is `DJXG/w1ARbM2ZOQ3pamMEkNY7qSJXpjbQMsARyWCr0Y=`. Our backend developers define what's correct

Comment: @damian-sketch So if you update your Python version and the new version doesn't use the spaces anymore, your Python code becomes wrong as well?

Comment: I believe we will figure out an appropriate solution for that when that time comes. Currently, I've been informed that the spaces should stay. So I guess I need to figure out a way to add spaces to the javascript version

Comment: I added a JavaScript version that inserts spaces. Try that.

Comment: I think you can just use the [optional `space` parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) of `JSON.stringify()` to add space automatically.

Comment: @jps that also adds line breaks

Comment: Line breaks... good idea. Much easier and safer to find.

Comment: Though in my opinion, trying to match a particular JSON formatting is still the wrong approach and they should talk to their backend developers to figure how a proper way to do whatever it is they're trying to do with this.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree that depending on the particular formatting of JSON is problematic.

Comment: Thanks @SimonLundberg, I used your latest JS updated code in conjuction with some little bit more of regex to get it done
`const refined = JSON.stringify(data, null, 1).match(/(\S.*)/gm).join(" ");`,
`const ref2 = refined.replace(/{\s/g, '{')`,
`const ref3 = ref2.replace(/\s}/g, '}')`